# What is the best way to have resizable fonts in a webpage

Tags: php, html, css, database

I have a medical webpage and in that people will input the data and get the printouts of the same. The problem now is, people want different types of fonts. I mean, for a single content individual person needs his individual fonts. And also, people need the alignment in different layouts. I am puzzled. do we have to save individual user settings in data base and draw the layout respectively or is there any other simple way?
 I hope i am clear with the requirement, let me know if not understood.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as too broad for SO, but to kind of answer the question in comment form, I think you need to take a step back and ask yourself *why* do people want different fonts and layouts? Is it there own preference, accessibility requirements, vision problems, etc? To an extend, you as the developer can dictate the font choice and layout given the requirements and, as long as the user experience is sound, require users to train on the new layout. Blindly trying to please everyone will not get you far.

Comment: As i said, its a medical app, and people want to use the same font and alignment in the report which they give to the patients, I have tried convincing, but still they feel they want their requirements. So i need to match them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a really, really broad question. First off, will patients select the font they want on the same page, or will it be in their user settings? This is important. For executing it, here is what I'd do:

- If you want to have users select it on the page, I'd use jquery to listen for an input on the user's form where they can select font size, and then "print" a span with the style appended to it. Very simple and fairly easy.
- If you want it to be in their user profile, you'll need to program php to select their settings, and print it to a span, appending the style of that span
- If you are looking for truly responsive dynamic font, I'd use a font style with the code: font-size: 1vh; where vh is a viewport that will resize based on the users' resolution.

Hope that helps. I think you are looking more at bullet 1 and 2, in which case Jquery or pulling from a database and printing it to a div in the code really is the best option.

In this community, it helps if you first try a few different methods, and then post some code that we can work off of. Helps to avoid wasting our/your time. Good luck!

Comment: See here i cannot put a code for this particular question since myself not in a stage to understand how to go with it. Anyways, i hope i can go with your second bulletin, which even i was thinking. Since the user need to have the same styles when he open the page, it should be stored